# What does the mtouch --argument command line option do?

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin.ios, command-line-arguments

Short version:

I've noticed that the recently updated `mtouch` (currently 5.2.5 for me) has some new command-line options - notably, `--launchdev`, which pleases me greatly, and `--argument`, which I cannot figure out how to use.  What does `--argument` do?  Can I use it to pass data into an application when I start it?  If so, where does that data *go*, and how do I get it?

---

Longer explanation of what I'm doing:

I have an automated test environment for our MonoTouch libraries.  In order for it to be truly automated, I needed to be able to 1) launch it automatically on the device, and 2) supply it with the IP address of the build server that launched it in the first place so it would know who to talk to when it is finished.

Currently, the only way I have found to shunt data into an iOS application is via custom URL schemes.  Coincidentally, this was also the only way I had to *launch* an application on a device automatically, as opposed to simply installing it.  So, my build script would build the test application, install it, script an Xcode project with the call to the custom URL scheme with the data the test application needed, and recite the proper AppleScript incantations to launch the Xcode project on the device.  The Xcode project would launch, and immediately call `openUrl(...)` with my test app's custom URL scheme and needed data, triggering the launch of the test application, which would run its tests, report the results and close.

I would be exceedingly pleased if, through some combination of `--launchdev` and `--argument`, I could cut out a large chunk of the above insanity - especially the AppleScript, which is very brittle and unreliable.

So far, I haven't figured how to use the values of `--argument` in code.  The `launchOptions` dictionary is `null` with or without it, and the `args` that are passed into Main disappear into the bowels of UIApplicationMain and are never heard from again, as far as I can tell - which doesn't matter anyway, because they are always empty.  So, can I use `--argument` to pass data in?  If so, how do I retrieve the data within the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit complicated and not properly documented, but here it goes:

`--argument=ARG` will pass ARG as a command line option to the application when launched (either on device or in the simulator). MonoTouch creates the native main method for the application, which is what handles ARG. And that native main method will pass any arguments like this: `-app-arg:MANAGED_ARG` to the managed Main method.

Putting this together, to pass for instance `-ip=3.14.15.9` to your app on the device, you'll execute mtouch like this:

```
mtouch --argument=-app-arg:-ip=3.14.15.9 --launchdev com.yourcompany.yourapp
```

Note that the native main method is a bit picky about the format, it's one dash (`-app-arg`, not `--app-arg`), and a colon before the MANAGED_ARG (not `=`).

Answer (score 2):

For others that are attempting to do this, I wanted demonstrate exactly what I had to do to use these arguments within my app, as well.

First, specify your argument on the command line, as Rolf said.  For each `--argument=-app-arg:SOMETHING` you put on the command line, you will get "SOMETHING" in your list of arguments.  Rolf's example,

```
mtouch --argument=-app-arg:-ip=3.14.15.9 --launchdev=com.yourcompany.yourapp
```

results in and argument list of `{ "-ip=3.14.15.9" }`.  If I did something like this

```
mtouch --argument=-app-arg:ARG1 --argument=-app-arg:ARG2=some_other_val --launchdev=com.yourcompany.yourapp
```

the resulting argument list is `{ "ARG1", "ARG2=some_other_val" }`.  There was nothing special about the dash before ip or the equals sign after it.  Just make sure you pass it in in a way that you'll be able to parse later.  ;)

Within your application, you can access these either in your `static void Main(string[] args)` method, which may be a little difficult since you don't have an AppDelegate or a UIViewController yet, or you can call `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` anywhere.  Note that the latter will have the actual call to your application in position 0, while the former will only have the arguments, not the application call.

If you need to include data with spaces, you may do so like this:

```
mtouch --argument=-app-arg:"This data has spaces" --launchdev=com.yourcompany.yourapp
```

Your resulting arg list will be `{ "This data has spaces" }`.  Without the quotes, you'll only get `{ "This" }`.  Further, remember that parameter substitution will happen with double quotes, but not single quotes:

```
SOMEVAR="value of SOMEVAR"
mtouch --argument=-app-arg:"SOMEVAR $SOMEVAR" --launchdev=com.yourcompany.yourapp
# Results in { "SOMEVAR value of SOMEVAR" }
mtouch --argument=-app-arg:'SOMEVAR $SOMEVAR' --launchdev=com.yourcompany.yourapp
# Results in { "SOMEVAR $SOMEVAR" }
```

Hopefully this helps anyone that was trying to do what I am until there is more official documentation on the `--argument` option.  Also, note that if you reference MonoTouch.NUnitLite, you can use `Mono.Options.OptionSet` to do the argument-parsing for you, if you don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism is being used at the moment to launch our unit tests applications on both the simulator and devices.

Documentation is not *yet* updated and the feature could change a bit before it is (it's all very recent). Right now you best bet is looking at [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit) source code, in particular this [commit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit/commit/ced0142aee7b023f7df8594b8eb43535890662ac#NUnitLite) by Rolf.